# Difference between nproc and ulimit?

Tags: linux, unix

Ulimit and nproc are both used for limiting the system processes and resources for a particular user or application (correct me if I am wrong) in *nix system. What is the major difference between the two?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 20):

There are two different instances of `nproc`.

`nproc` from `coreutils` prints the number of processors. From `man nproc`:

```
NPROC(1)                         User Commands                        NPROC(1)

NAME
       nproc - print the number of processing units available

SYNOPSIS
       nproc [OPTION]...

DESCRIPTION
       Print  the number of processing units available to the current process,
       which may be less than the number of online processors
```

**However, the `nproc` setting in `/etc/security/limits.conf` indeed limits the number of processes**:

From `man limits.conf`:

```
       nproc
           maximum number of processes
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 both are used for limiting the system processes and resources
```

If you are referring to the nproc parameter in [**limits.conf**](https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf) then yes it's for limiting the number of processes.

The shell utility [**ulimit**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ulimit.1p.html) is used for getting/setting resources' limits, too. For example, getting the stack size for each process:

```
$ulimit -s
```

Changing the stack size to 1MB:

```
$ulimit -s 1024
```

Changing the stack size to `unlimited`:

```
$ulimit -s unlimited
```

There's no difference between setting/changing resources via ``` /etc/security/limits.conf`` and ```ulimit`.

However, the shell utility `ulimit` changes are only applicable to the current shell. But /etc/security/limits.conf changes will be applicable system-wide for all the specified users. Besides /etc/security/limits.conf typically can be changed only by a privileged users.

But `ulimit` doesn't require privileges.

So you can think of `ulimit` as for temporary changes to resource limits *just for you*, which you can change yourself; whereas `/etc/security/limits.conf` is for system-wide setting (for one or more users) which you can't usually change (typically your system administrators sets resource limits, if any).

---

Whereas `nproc(1)` utliity is totally different which just lists the available number of processors.

Comment: The C function `ulimit` has been marked obsolete; the shell command `ulimit` has not.